# From Database Schema to pretty Diagram - Automated Tools for basic SQL Lite Schema?

Tags: sqlite, diagram

I was wondering if there are any **automated** tools for displaying a database schema diagrammatically?

My artistic side fails me and it would be nice to open my discussion with a diagram which doesn't scream ugly.

Many thanks,

Gav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are plenty of tools, especially commercial ones such as [DeZign](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/index.html). Are you looking for free SW, or could you afford a few hundred dollars for a license?

Edit: since you've clarified you have no funding for such tools, let me point out that there are free ("as in, free beer";-) possibilities, too -- for example, there is supposed to be a "Free Edition" of the commercial package DBVisualizer (the site of the firm producing that package talks repeatedly about this free edition but appears to only offer links to the evaluation version, for which you'd have to purchase a license after a while; however, with a web search I see several links to free-edition downloads, maybe a few versions back). I have no experience with this package (in either edition) but it may be worth your while to try!

Comment: Hi Alex, this is for a University research project so unfortunately I'm looking for some free software.

Thanks for the link though I'll run it by my prof

Comment: Free 30 day trial has done the trick. Many thanks!